# OpenSSL storage size of 'hashctx' isn't known

Tags: c, hash, openssl

Despite having just updated openssl to 1.0.2r, I'm getting the error stated in the title. I did some looking around and supposedly this is usually caused by having an older version installed, hence why I updated, though this has not fixed the error. The code that is failing is:

```
            EVP_MD_CTX hashctx;
            EVP_MD *hashptr = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA512");

            EVP_MD_CTX_init(&hashctx);
            EVP_DigestInit_ex(&hashctx, hashptr, NULL));

            do {
              len = fread(buffer, 1, BUFSIZ, hashInBuf);
              EVP_DigestUpdate(&hashctx, buffer, len);
            } while (len == BUFSIZ);

            EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&hashctx, buffer, &len);
            EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&hashctx);
```

I've tried defining `hashctx` after `main` however this has not remedied the issue.

`hashInBuf` is a defined/opened file, `len` is set as `size_t len;`, and `BUFSIZ` set as `unsigned char buffer[BUFSIZ]` (all below main).

Comment: Missing a `#include` maybe? Post **[complete](/help/mcve)** code and the complete error message.

Comment: This is actually usually caused by compiling against *newer* OpenSSL. If you are picking up headers from OpenSSL 1.1.0 or above then you will get this error with the above code. Declare hashctx as `EVP_MD_CTX *hashctx`, alocate it with `EVP_MD_CTX_new` instead of `EVP_MD_CTX_init` and then free it with `EVP_MD_CTX_free` instead of `EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup`.